# Need a Haar Cascade for lip

Tags: python, ios, c#-4.0, opencv, face-detection

I need a Haar cascaded file for lip detection only. I have searched in openCV

I have gone to this link http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34
but there is no Haar cascade file that will detect only lip detection.

Anybody can provide me this file or can you give me any reference of tools or software that will generate Haar Cascaded xml file accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) on how to generate your own cascade with the help of OpenCV.